# iPhone Development: Use of MKReverseGeocoder

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mkreversegeocoder

Does anyone know if MKReverseGeocoder can be used in commercial apps/paid apps? The Google Maps Terms of Service are not very clear on that (to me).

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The Google terms of service require
>   that the reverse geocoding service be
>   used in conjunction with a Google map;
>   take this into account when designing
>   your application's user interface.

So as long as you are using a MKMapView to display the results of the reverse GeoCode request, you are fine.